# Problem with Macros in TexStudio

Tags: macros, texstudio

I'm new to LaTeX and TexStudio, and I want the environment for equation to be typed in if I type `"\eq"`. So I tried setting `\eq` as a trigger for:

```
\begin{equation}
content...
\end{equation}
```

However, the macro doesn't work as expected. Simply typing `"eq"` produces the macro. I can't even type the word "equals".

Further, when I type `\eq` an autocomplete window opens. [image: Autocomplete window]

How do I program the macro to produce the equation environment on typing nothing but `\eq`?

Edit: Here's how I added the macro and set it up:

[image: Macro setup]

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks a lot, buddy. Can you help me out with my lil problem, sir?

Comment: How did you set up "\eq as a trigger for ..."?

Comment: Try to use a trigger which does not correspond to the beginning of so many commands. Why not use `\eqn`?

Comment: @samcarter added your query to the question

Comment: @Bernard Is it not possible to set up `\eq` to be a macro as I want it?

Note: I WANT to have to type `backslash` before `eq` for the macro to work. But even when I don't include the `backslash` it still works. How do I correct this?

Comment: @Somenath Sinha: For the trigger, replace `\eq` with `\eq ` (with a space at the end). Then typing `eq ` (with a space) will work.

Comment: @Bernard is it possible to use `backslash` as a part of the trigger? As in, I'd like to type `\eq` instead of just `eq`

Comment: I don't know sufficiently well TeXstudio macro language to answer. Just try it. What bad with `eq `? This is not an existing word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two issues with your setup:

1. Triggers are regular expressions. Therefore you need to escape the backslash: `\\eq`
2. As written in [the manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#sectionTriggers):

> Triggers are inactive while the completer is active. For example you cannot trigger on `\\sec` if the completer is open suggesting to complete `\section`.

You cannot use both, a `\\`-starting trigger and the completer at the same time.

**Possible solutions:**

- deactivate `Options -> Completion -> Automatically start completer when typing LaTeX commands`.

or alternatively:

- use another trigger, e.g. `#eq`

Answer (score 2):

Inside TexStudio macros one can define commands as well as triggers. So you could add `\eq` in the "Abbreviation" field, like so:
[image: Image of \eq]

When writting the command, autocompletion will popup, but the first option will be your newly create command.

Answer (score -2):

Better use this in the preamble
\def{\beq}{\begin{equation}}
\def{\eeq}{\end{equation}}
Now you can write equation between
\beq  and \eeq
Your idea does not work easily.

Comment: I disagree, using `\beq` is far from more readable,  in no way better code and no faster (indeed it seems like more key presses) to type. The OP is in my opinion asking for assistance in applying this better practice (so I don't feel that this answers the question) and given they have accepted an answer I assume they have been able to achieve the desired functionality.